# ADSL Modem + Router: Disabling router

Tags: router, adsl, pppoe, adsl2+

I have two devices to establish my home network and internet connection:

- A Sitecom DC-227 ADSL Modem + Router (Modem)
- A Sitecom Router + Switch (Router)

Currently I've set it up using double routing and NAT. Between the modem and the router there is a network in the 10.0.0.0/8 range, and the real LAN behind the router is in the 192.168.2.0/24 range.

This works fine for regular internetting. However, I want to run some servers in the 192.x network, and I can't forward external ports correctly from the modem. I've set it up in its config panel, but it doesn't appear to work. This may be because it's a feature called "virtual servers", while the router has "real" port forwarding.

So I'd rather set up the modem to just bridge between ADSL/Ethernet, and have the router as the only router. How do I set this up? I tried setting the modem to "1483 Bridged" mode and set PPPoE on the router, but that didn't work. I don't know if I got all the details right though.

My current settings are: **Modem:**

- Protocol: PPPoA
- VPI/VCI: 8/48
- Encapsulation: VC MUX
- Username: kpn@direct-adsl
- Password: kpn (it's the same for everyone)
- Own IP: 10.0.0.1

**Router:**

- WAN side: static IP 10.0.0.2
- LAN side: IP 192.168.2.2, DHCP server for 192.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is take your second device - the one you are now using as a router - and just use it as a switch.

Take the Ethernet from the modem and instead of plugging into the WAN port on the second device, plug it into a switch port. This eliminates the intermediary network and the modem will be the NAT router serving 192.x (or its default 10.x, doesn't matter). It looks like the DC-227 has decent standard features - firewall, QoS and, most importantly for your needs, DMZ and port forwarding.

Comment: I know that trick, but the port forwarding on the DC-227 doesn't work. It doesn't matter, we switched out both devices for a single Linksys modem+router.

Comment: That's a fine solution.